# How to use python socket to get a html page

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I found that by socket.connect(host,port),I can get this page. But there are some limitations on the format of host. For example, I can get from www.reddit.com, but if I want to get a specific web page like www.reddit.com/r/AccidentalRenaissance/comments/8ciibe/mr_fluffies_betrayal/(randomly choose one page), I will get [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed error. How to fix this issue?
My code is:(under python2.6)

```
import socket
import sys
import re
import os

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = 'www.reddit.com/r/AccidentalRenaissance/comments/8ciibe/mr_fluffies_betrayal/'
try:
    socket.gethostbyname(host)
except Exception,e:
    print(type(e))
    print(e)
port = 80
request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: "+host+"\r\n\r\n"
s.sendall(request.encode())
contest = s.recv(1024).decode()
print(contest)
```

For the mentioned website, I will get:

```
<class 'socket.gaierror'>
[Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Anyone knows how to fix this issue by only using socket package?

Answer (score 1):

The format of the GET is incorrect. And you need to connect to the socket:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
request = "GET /r/AccidentalRenaissance/comments/8ciibe/mr_fluffies_betrayal/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.reddit.com\r\n\r\n"
s.connect(("www.reddit.com", 80))
s.sendall(request.encode())
contest = s.recv(1024).decode()
s.close()
print(contest)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, I think I actually know how it works. I will try to fix mine

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [@Jonhy Mopp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669576/johnny-mopp) for your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49848565/11688889) it fixed the `[Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed` error.

Testing the provided example in the question I was not able to connect even after fixing the `[Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed` error, and the reason is because reddit requires a SSL connection.

The following works to connect via a SSL connection:

```
import socket
import ssl

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
request = "GET /r/AccidentalRenaissance/comments/8ciibe/mr_fluffies_betrayal/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.reddit.com\r\n\r\n"

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
s = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname = "www.reddit.com")

s.connect(("www.reddit.com", 443))
s.sendall(request.encode())

contest = s.recv(1024).decode()

s.close()
print(contest)
```

Answer (score -1):

Uhh,Bro u should know that.
What the para is A HOST but not a html!

```
    host must be a “host”
```